# stability of negative feedback amplifier

Tags: feedback, stability

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_feedback

Wikipedia says the O/I =A/(1+βA)
When I set A=1 β=10, then O/I becomes 1/11
But when I put 1mv sin wave as input, the magnitude of signal after passing β is 10mv and (1mv-10mv) sin wave becomes input and the magnitude of signal after passing β is -90mv and input becomes again 1-(-90)=91mv.
When I calculate this again and again, the magnitude of absolute value of output seems to go infinite and the system seems to be unstable. But above calculation shows the O/I is finite. What's wrong to my thinking?

Comment: beta is always less than 1.

Comment: "A" for Op Amps is usually 1e6 !

Comment: Then , if I set A=10 β=0.5 and put 1mv input
Then the input becomes (1-5)mv and 1-(-20)mv, (1-105)mv 
For this case, if we calculate again and again, the magnitude of output seems to increase to infinite....
What is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given formula for the output takes into the account that the signal itself iterates around the feedback loop until the balance is found. In practice one can see with the oscilloscope that the right output does not get stabilized instantneously due the slow operation of the electronic components.

You obviously wanted to do the same iteration which is done in the feedback loop. Unfortunately using discrete steps does not allways lead gradually towards the balance, the iteration can diverge altough the solution exists.The math theory of numerically solving equations is anything but simple.

Just in this case the divergence of the iteration is obvious. You are actually numerically simulating the circuit with an included delay with infinite bandwidth and that naturally makes the systen an oscillator. The amplitude grows infinitely due no limitations. The delay time = your simulation step. You did not mean it, but you included it.

To avoid the implied infinite bandwidth delay you can for example assume some RC lowpass filtering to exist. To get realistic result you should assume one iteration round to present so short time interval that the output of the RC filter does not change very much.